# Give an example such that $\{a_n\}$ is a divergent sequence and its subsequences {a_2k} and {a_3k} converges to same number.

Tags: real-analysis

I am having a hard time finding such an example. This may be a simple question but I am very new to analysis. Finding such $\{a_n\}$, where $\{a_{2k}\}$ converges to a number seems easy and one such example could be $\{(-1)^n\}$. In addition, if they asked for such sequences where two subsequences converge to different numbers sine may help us, but this question is a bit out of my range or probably I am missing something super basic.
Can I get some help, please!

Comment: You had written $\{(-1)^{\color{red}{2}}\}$ as your example. Judging from your comment on an answer, I'm guessing you meant $\{(-1)^{\color{red}{n}}\}$. I have made that change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically inspired by the other answer but more suited to your needs since you said that you want to use an "explicit" function.
Define $$a_{n} = \sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{3}\right).$$
Note that $a_{2k} = a_{3k} = 0$ for all $k \in \Bbb N$ since one of the terms will vanish for all indices.
Check that this does not actually converge.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for...
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Let $a_n$ be a sequence defined as follows :
$ a_{2k}=a_{3k} = 0 \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$
$ a_{n} = 1 $ otherwise.
The sequence above indeed diverge, yet the subsequences $a_{2k}$ and $a_{3k}$ converge to $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This solution looks trivial but I was particularly looking for some kind of function. Is there any function that can help to achieve this sequence?

Comment: Do you mean a sequence defined by : $a_n=f(n)$ where $f$ is a function ?

Comment: yup, I am trying to figure out a single function rather than a piecewise function, just out of curiosity. I tried sine function, functions of the form (-1)^n and currently I am trying to use gcd or mod to get the desired answer even though I am not super comfortable using mod.